# Environment specific properties in JBOSS AS7

Tags: java, spring, deployment, properties, jboss

We have 4 servers that run JBOSS AS7:

- dev
- test
- acc
- prod

On each jboss, a simple webapp will run. This webapp will use spring and requires some properties to be set like:

```
webservice.endpoint=interface.url.com
webservice.port=7676
```

The properties will differ for each environment. The way we handle this at this moment is as follows:

I have a JAR file with a single file in it, config.properties. This property file contains all my properties. I turn this jar into a global jboss module and configure it in my `domain.xml` (or `standalone.xml`) to be included. This works, because spring can access the properties when making beans.

However, it seems overly complicated to turn properties into a jar, into a module. I was thinking I should maybe use system properties to achieve this? My  question is: is this a good place to put all the environment specific, application specific properties? Will they be loaded into the JVM so everyone can access them at will (especially Spring, which uses the `${myProperty}` notation to access properties). Additionally, when I add properties using the console in my browser, were are they stored? I cannot see them in `domain.xml` or `host.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

if you go with the **JAR** solution :
 - use an unique classifier for each environments. You will have x properties files : dev_config.properties / test_config.properties, etc...

this way you can just set an unique JAVA_OPTS that set the environment in which you are.
then you get the right properties file :

using :    `System.getenv("ENV")` or `System.getProperty("ENV")`

```
if ("DEV".Equals(System.getenv("ENV"))
  here you load ==> the dev_config.properties
```

to load the properties into a JAR it is really easy with this maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>packaging-deployment_manifests_bundle</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>descriptors/deployment_manifests_bundle.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

if you go with the **environment_variables** :
I never tried this solution in my projects, I always went with the properties file solution. but if you have just a few variables to set, this could be even quicker... you can access those variables with :

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

Adding data in the environments variables can be OK if it is nothing sensitive, like passwords and the likes. 
It is easier IMO to obfuscate data in a properties file. So if security is at stake, this is a point to consider.

Answer (score 0):

At my company, we're used to store environment dependent properties in the database. This means you have a database for each environment. Not sure your application has a database to store these, though.

Another solution would be to use a system property, that you either define differently on each server, or change at execution time when you launch the server:

- define in your standalone.xml , with a `default` that will be used if no `my.cmd-line-descriptor` is specified

  ```
  <system-properties>
    <property name="my-specific-value" value="${my.cmd-line-descriptor:default}"/>
    ...
  </system-properties>
  ```
- change it if necessary at appserver startup:

  ```
  java ... -Dmy.cmd-line-descriptor=another-value
  ```

For you additional question, I would suggest you look for the changes done from the console in the `tmp/vfs` directories of your appservers

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven in the project you can set these properties by environment in the different profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
       <id>dev</id>
       <properties>
         <webservice.endpoint>interface.url.com</webservice.endpoint>
         <webservice.port>7676</webservice.port>
       </properties>
     </profile>
     <profile>
       <id>test</id>
       <properties>
         <webservice.endpoint>test url</webservice.endpoint>
         <webservice.port>whatever port</webservice.port>
       </properties>
     </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then, when you compile the project you have to specify the environment you are compiling it for in the -P parameter to use the properties of that profile:

```
maven clean install -P dev
```

Then you can access to these properties using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot see them in domain.xml or host.xml

They are there right on top level in `<server>` for standalone or `<domain>` for domain like that

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.7"> 
...
    <system-properties>
        <property name="myapp.env" value="dev"/>
    </system-properties>
...
</server>
```

then Spring can see it as `${myapp.env}`or any other code as system properites.

They can be set from JBoss Admin Console as well in "Configuration" tab at very bottom there is "System properties" - it is actually content of that `<system-properties>` tag in domain.xml

Also they can be used inside domain.xml.
 As example if you have your myapp.properties files in different directories based on environment you can do it as:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.7"> 
...
<system-properties>
    <property name="myapp.env" value="dev"/>
    <property name="myapp.config.file" value="${myapp.env}/myapp.properties"/>
</system-properties>
...
```

So path to file will be `dev/myapp.properties` and Spring will see it as ${myapp.config.file} then can load properties from there.

PS. Also as I remember specific System properties can be set in the Module definition or even in application deployment descriptor `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` - not sure about last one... BTW it is not a case for your question about differentiate by environment.

PPS. About how .properties store in file system - Keep them in JAR file is a bad idea. it needs a rebuild and deployment every time when some property changed.

.properties files are there to avoid that. So they have to be outside of deployment.

So it depends on organization network policy.

Once in a while it was NFS directory with different file names like dev_myapp.properties, test_myapp.properties etc.

Other time it was one NFS directory with subdirectories - dev, test etc. with the same file name in each.

In my current organization NFS is not allowed. Each Slave instance in cluster has it's own clone of file in exact same location i.e. `config/myapp.properties`. so, there is only one system property defined as path to that file. Each environment has it's own version of file.

good luck!